# Getting find text (Ctrl+F) different highlighted text result

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to know texts and their location in DOM highlighted by Chrome's find text (Ctrl+F)?

If it is, how can I know which one is being strong-highlighted (orange), and which one is being weak-highlighted (yellow)?

[image]

Comment: I suppose the 1st/active element is defined as orange & others as yellow.

Comment: I can't see anything in chrome's apis about this. Maybe somewhere in the webkit api?