# Where in chromium's source code is ctrl+f handled?

Tags: open-source, chromium

I'm trying to understand how the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> feature works in chromium. I thought of having a look directly in the source code, but the code is rather large and complex. Does anyone know where the code concerning the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> feature is?

**Related question**: [Getting find text (Ctrl+F) different highlighted text result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868272/getting-find-text-ctrlf-different-highlighted-text-result)

Comment: This almost seems funny enough to be a joke. I almost answered "Use CTRL+F and search through the source"

Comment: @Kyle Macey Which search terms do you suggest I use?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was kidding. No clue, bud. What are you looking to do?

Comment: I'm developing a chrome extension which could profit from interacting with the ctrl+f feature, but since I can't find anything about it in the chrome APIs, I thought I would check out the source code to see if there's anything in there I can use. In any case, I can at least get a look at the algorithm for inspiration's sake...